# Convert strings in column into categorical variable

Tags: python, string, pandas, statistics, categorical-data

I'd like to transform columns filled with strings into categorical variables so that I could run statistics. However, I am having difficulty with this transformation because I'm fairly new to Python.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
# Open txt file and provide column names
data = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep="\t", header = None,
                   names = ["Label", "I1", "I2", "C1", "C2"])
# Convert I1 and I2 to continuous, numeric variables
data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
# Convert Label, C1, and C2 to categorical variables
data["Label"] = pd.factorize(data.Label)[0]
data["C1"] = pd.factorize(data.C1)[0]
data["C2"] = pd.factorize(data.C2)[0]

# Split the predictors into training/testing sets
predictors = data.drop('Label', 1)
msk = np.random.rand(len(predictors)) < 0.8
predictors_train = predictors[msk]
predictors_test = predictors[~msk]

# Split the response variable into training/testing sets
response = data['Label']
ksm = np.random.rand(len(response)) < 0.8
response_train = response[ksm]
response_test = response[~ksm]

# Logistic Regression
from sklearn import linear_model
# Create logistic regression object
lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
lr.fit(predictors_train, response_train)
```

However, I'd get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ec26ad35'
```

The `ec26ad35` value is a string from the categorical variables `C1` and `C2`. I'm not sure what's going on: Didn't I already convert the strings into categorical variables? Why does the error say that they're still strings?

Using `data.head(30)`, this is my data:

```
>> data[["Label", "I1", "I2", "C1", "C2"]].head(30)
    Label   I1   I2        C1        C2
0       0  1.0    1  68fd1e64  80e26c9b
1       0  2.0    0  68fd1e64  f0cf0024
2       0  2.0    0  287e684f  0a519c5c
3       0  NaN  893  68fd1e64  2c16a946
4       0  3.0   -1  8cf07265  ae46a29d
5       0  NaN   -1  05db9164  6c9c9cf3
6       0  NaN    1  439a44a4  ad4527a2
7       1  1.0    4  68fd1e64  2c16a946
8       0  NaN   44  05db9164  d833535f
9       0  NaN   35  05db9164  510b40a5
10      0  NaN    2  05db9164  0468d672
11      0  0.0    6  05db9164  9b5fd12f
12      1  0.0   -1  241546e0  38a947a1
13      1  NaN    2  be589b51  287130e0
14      0  0.0   51  5a9ed9b0  80e26c9b
15      0  NaN    2  05db9164  bc6e3dc1
16      1  1.0  987  68fd1e64  38d50e09
17      0  0.0    1  8cf07265  7cd19acc
18      0  0.0   24  05db9164  f0cf0024
19      0  7.0  102  3c9d8785  b0660259
20      1  NaN   47  1464facd  38a947a1
21      0  0.0    1  05db9164  09e68b86
22      0  NaN    0  05db9164  38a947a1
23      0  NaN    9  05db9164  08d6d899
24      0  0.0    1  5a9ed9b0  3df44d94
25      0  NaN    4  5a9ed9b0  09e68b86
26      1  0.0    1  8cf07265  942f9a8d
27      1  0.0   20  68fd1e64  38a947a1
28      1  0.0   78  68fd1e64  1287a654
29      1  3.0    0  05db9164  90081f33
```

**Edit**: Included error from imputing missing data after splitting dataframes into training and testing data sets. Not sure what's going on here too.

```
# Impute missing data
>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>> imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
>> predictors_train = imp.fit_transform(predictors_train)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

Comment: I don't know what that variable is, but for categorical variables you need to use [dummy variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37144372/2285236) in linear regression.

Comment: If you post a sample from your dataframe I can suggest a pandas solution for that as well.

Comment: What is your dependent variable? Is it label? If so, is it a numerical variable (it should be if you are going to use linear regression).

Comment: @ayhan you're right. I'll make the adjustment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ayhan noted in the comments, you probably want to use [dummy variables](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/dummyvar.php) here. This is because it seems highly unlikely from your data that there is really any ordering in your text labels.

This can easily be done via [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), e.g.:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.C1)
```

Note that this returns a regular DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.C1).columns
Index([u'05db9164', u'1464facd', u'241546e0', u'287e684f', u'3c9d8785',
     u'439a44a4', u'5a9ed9b0', u'68fd1e64', u'8cf07265', u'be589b51'],
     dtype='object')
```

You'd probably want to use this with a horizontal [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), therefore.

---

If you actually are actually looking to transform the labels into something numeric (which does not seem likely), you might look at [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I'm unsure when you at the code, but I made some modifications that would change the strings into factors in a categorical variable.